# How to update state value to textarea using onChange?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, onchange

Currently following a slightly older tutorial, but learning using React 18 -- trying to update the `text area` in a notes app

It looks like when I type, a character appears and then immediately is deleted automatically

Can anyone confirm if I might be missing a detail here?

for reference if familiar with the project at time 1:37:03 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fM3ueN9nYM&t=377s

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import notes from '../assets/data'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ReactComponent as ArrowLeft } from '../assets/arrow-left.svg'


const NotePage = ( history ) => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    // let note = notes.find(note => note.id===Number(id))
    // console.log(id)
    let [note, setNote] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        getNote()
    }, [{id}])

    let getNote = async () => {
        let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/notes/${id}`)
        let data = await response.json()
        setNote(data)
    }

    // let updateNote = async () => {
    //     await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/notes/${id}`, {
    //         method: 'PUT',
    //         headers: {
    //             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    //         },
    //         body: JSON.stringify({...note, 'updated':new Date()})
    //     }) 
    // }

    // let handleSubmit = () => {
    //     updateNote()
    //     history.push('/')
    // }

  return (
    <div className="note">
        <div className="note-header">
            <h3>
                <Link to="/">
                    <ArrowLeft /*onClick={handleSubmit}*/ />
                </Link>
            </h3>
        </div>

        <textarea onChange={(e) => { 
            setNote({...note, 'body': e.target.value}) }} 
            value={note?.body}>
        </textarea>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NotePage
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value in the useEffect dependency array is incorrect and causing `getNote` to be called every time you make changes in the `textArea`. Every time `getNote` is called, it's resetting the note state back to whataver is being received by `getNote`. Which in your case is probably a blank note

Change this :

```
useEffect(() => {
  getNote();
}, [{ id }]);
```

To this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getNote();
}, [id]);
```